# Getting "On Behalf Of" in ubercart email confirmation

Tags: ubercart, commerce

I am using ubercart in my site.  After making the payment we are getting two emails.  One is for the user and another for admin.  In the amin email I am getting "On Behalf of" and id of the developer who developed this app.  How to change it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look in modules folder, in

site root folder /sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_order/templates/uc-order--admin.tpl.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply..  I will check that file and let you know..